# Able to POST form from browser to server but not server to server

Tags: c#, post, netsuite

I'm trying to send a POST request to a net suite server. It works perfectly fine when I send it using a form on a browser; however when I send the request using C#, I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Here's my code for the C# Code-behind POST:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://forms.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalleadpage.nl");

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();  //error is here.
```

I'm almost positive I'm sending the same parameters through as it is a simple form.

Comment: Install fiddler and compare the two requests, then you will see a difference. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Encoding.ASCII? So no umlauts, accented characters etc in your data?

Comment: You may also try Postman, which is an extension/app for Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Add a user-agent header that mimics a current browser. That works with Suitelets.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.
It was a netsuite configuration problem; the redirect url was set to / which caused a response either unable to parse or null.